# Set Label control on BezierSegment path

Tags: c#, wpf, position, label, bezier

I understand the concept of drawing the path using BezierSegment.
However, can I set label control position onto the path? Thks!!

Comment: Is this in WPF? Do you mean setting (x,y) of label to a point on the bezier curve? Whether the label has to change the position or it is a one time positioning? What's the code that you are having?

Comment: Yes. It's position will change on swipe. The new position will be somewhere along the curve depend if the user swipe to left or right.

Comment: +1 for your query. I found few approaches discussed on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503476/position-images-along-a-bezier-curve and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920687/position-of-a-point-relative-to-a-bezier-curve. Someone who has implemented a working soution can answer this. Finding a point on bezier curve http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/de-casteljau.html

Comment: Thks! However I still face issue on setting the position along the curve. I'm trying to create a path using style and hopefully add the position of the label to the path. Is it the right way? I manage to draw a curve using path and am now stuck at placing the label control along it. Please advise. Thanks!